# How can I create delay in iOS Swift so task A ends before task B begins?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically what I need is followings:

1. start task A (play sound)
2. wait until task A finish
3. start task B (listen to mic for 4 seconds)
4. stop task B
5. repeat 1-4

I use dispatch_after for step 3 and 4 but that didn't work. The simulator played all the sound files without listening to the mic. How can I fix this problem?

```
@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    var words = ["laud","puff","keen","death","knock"]
    for item in words {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(item, ofType: "m4a")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
            player.delegate = self
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print("Error AVAudioPlayer")
        }

        while player.playing {
            print("Playing")
        }
        print("stop playing")

        startListening()

        let seconds = 4.0
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.stopListening()
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `startListening`? Any chance that that function runs asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `NSTimer`:

```
let timer  = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), target: self, selector: "stopListening:", userInfo: "", repeats: false)
```

Comment: This solution will solve `listen to mic for 4 seconds`, which between `step 3` and `step 4` that op mentioned. However, we may need to implement `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` to achieve `step 2`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already set `player.delegate = self`, you need to implement the method ([See documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:))

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)
```

to catch the event that audio playing was finished

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        startLitening()
    }
}
```

Then, you can use @John 's answer which is NSTimer to do the remaining tasks

```
let seconds = 4.0
let timer  = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), target: self, selector: "stopListening:", userInfo: "", repeats: false)

stopListening() {
    // do anything else
    playAudioAgain()
}
```

Comment: I had no trouble with Step 2  using while loop. AudioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is an alternative to the while loop.